# PyQt4 Adding a custom widget derived from another custom widget to layout

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to build a widget structure which will have a base widget which is derived from QtGui.QWidget, then I'll put the base features I want in every widget I create. Once the base widget is done, i'll create other types of widgets derived from the base widget.

here is an example

```py
class TurquoiseWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="Widget", enable_title=False, font_size=9):
        super(TurquoiseWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(self.minimumSize())
        self.widget_area = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.widget_area.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.Box)
        self.widget_area.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)

        title_lbl = QtGui.QLabel(title)
        font = title_lbl.font()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        # font.setFamily("Quicksand")
        font.setPointSize(font_size)
        title_lbl.setFont(font)
        title_lyt = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        title_lyt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        title_lyt.addWidget(title_lbl)


        main_lyt = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_lyt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        if enable_title:
            main_lyt.addLayout(title_lyt)
        main_lyt.addWidget(self.widget_area)
        self.setLayout(main_lyt)



class ArmControlWidget(TurquoiseWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ArmControlWidget, self).__init__()
        self.arm_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Arm")
        self.disarm_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Disarm")
        self.arm_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Arm(True))
        self.disarm_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Arm(False))
        self.srv = rospy.ServiceProxy("/mavros/cmd/arming", CommandBool)

        lyt = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lyt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        lyt.addWidget(self.disarm_button)
        lyt.addWidget(self.arm_button)
        self.widget_area.setLayout(lyt)

    def Arm(self, arm):
        srv_msg = CommandBoolRequest()
        srv_msg.value = arm
        print self.srv(srv_msg)




class StatusToolbar(TurquoiseWidget):
    """docstring for StatusToolbar."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(StatusToolbar, self).__init__()
        self.lyt = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.a = ArmControlWidget()
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.a)
        # self.lyt.addWidget(ArmControlWidget())
        self.widget_area.setLayout(self.lyt)
```

In this case the TurquoiseWidget is the base widget (every base widget has a frame and a title label in it.), ArmControlWidget is a widget performs spesific task and the StatusToolbar is the toolbar object, which has a set of widgets inside of it that derives from TurquoiseWidget or base widget.

So when I just do 
    some_widget = ArmControlWidget()
    some_widget.show()
it works perfectly. But when I create this widget inside of toolbar widget and display it in there, nothing shows.

Sorry if I'm not clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Here is what I try to do completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the minimum size of a widget that has no children? You can be very small and when you set it as a fixed size the widget will have a small size even if you have other widgets or layouts. So the solution is to remove the line `self.setFixedSize(self.minimumSize())` and add to the end of the constructor of the `StatusToolbar` `self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())`.

```
class TurquoiseWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="Widget", enable_title=False, font_size=9):
        super(TurquoiseWidget, self).__init__()
        # self.setFixedSize(self.minimumSize()) delete this line
        self.widget_area = QtGui.QFrame()
        # ...

# ...

class StatusToolbar(TurquoiseWidget):
    """docstring for StatusToolbar."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(StatusToolbar, self).__init__()
        self.lyt = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.a = ArmControlWidget()
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.a)
        self.widget_area.setLayout(self.lyt)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint()) # add this line
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, actually I must have left it out there, but it didn't cause any problems using widget.show(), it was set to minimum size and that line was before adding push buttons etc, so I never thought that might be the case.